# 'UIViewController initWithNibName:' causes error 'view outlet not set' (can't solve with known answers)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, xib

I have `UIViewController` subclass with `xib` file. I created the xib as empty file and moved view controller with content from another storyboard file (maybe it matters). When I instantiate the view controller with `initWithNibName:... bundle:...` it raises `view outlet not set` error.

But, if I set `File's owner` class to my view controller and associate it's view to main view of view controller than another exception raises: `A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!... Clear this association before associating this view...`

[image]

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the *view* with the nib, not the *view controller*. You may be able to drag the view out of the view controller and connect it directly (and delete the extra view controller object).

Comment: Maybe there is a way to keep existing view controller in xib? If I extract root view from view controller I should re-associate all IBOutlets and autolayout constraints can break.

Comment: If you are instantiating the view controller with `alloc/init` (or any other initializer), then the nib cannot contain the view controller object, except as the File's Owner placeholder.